# "Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element" error from Ean Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am going to add EAN Hotel API into my Website or other Application.
I add the SOAP WSDL Web Reference from :
http://api.ean.com/ean-services/ws/hotel/v3?wsdl

And now i want to get the hotel Info.
I'm getting error : 
Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://v3.hotel.wsapi.ean.com/",local:"HotelListRequest"). Expected elements are <{}HotelListRequest>

And my sample code is :

```
var hotelService = new HotelServicesClient("HotelServicesImplPort");
            var hotelRequest = new HotelInformationRequest
            {
                cid = 55505,// Your CID
                apiKey = "wyju58sf64tpnf2mwj8x2s8b", // Your API Key
                minorRev = 99,
                customerIpAddress = " 178.131.228.12",
                hotelId = 122212                    
            };

HotelInformationResponse response = hotelService.getInformation(hotelRequest);
Response.Write(response);
```